# add/append alt value dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic, append

Newbie (perhaps stupid) question: How can I use the value of "alt" in the code below to add/append it to "img" (between the "img" and "a" end tags)? I haven't been able to find examples out there on anything else than how to add/append hard coded text, but I want it to be done dynamically.

```
$html .= '<a href="#imgshow" data-transition="pop" data-index="'.$i.'" data-rel="dialog" id="thumb">
        <img src="https://[someurl]/'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'">
        </img></a>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery for all img with afteralt css class (php and jQuery codes);

PHP;

```
$html .= '<a href="#imgshow" data-transition="pop" data-index="'.$i.'" data-rel="dialog" id="thumb">
        <img src="https://[someurl]/'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'" class='afteralt'>
        </img></a>'
```

jQuery:

```
$.each($("img.afteralt"), function() { 
  $(this).after($(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

Comment: This is simple and works well with my code, I'll go with this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$html .= '<a href="#imgshow" data-transition="pop" data-index="'.$i.'" data-rel="dialog" id="thumb">
        <img src="https://[someurl]/'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'">
        </img>'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'</a>'
```

please note that you should write `<img />` and not `<img></img>` (the forward slash is requested only using xhtml) so the right code should be

```
$html .= '<a href="#imgshow" data-transition="pop" data-index="'.$i.'" data-rel="dialog" id="thumb">
         <img src="https://[someurl]/'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'" />'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code

```
$('a#thumb').html($('a#thumb').html()+$('a#thumb').children('img').attr('alt'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes my code replace all other images in the gallery with the first image and it's name (dynamically), so it's almost what I need :)

Comment: You welcome. You may upvote this, so others can notice it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the data, locate the useful data first and then compile the output as needed. You can use the data everywhere you want to:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($xml->COM->MOVIE as $i => $movie)
{
    $url = 'https://[someurl]/'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($movie->attributes()->dbIcoFilename));
    $alt = $movie->attributes()->nameS;
    $html .= sprintf(
    '<a href="#imgshow" data-transition="pop" data-index="%d" data-rel="dialog" id="thumb">
        <img src="%s" alt="%3$s">
        </img>%3$s</a>'
        , $i, $url, htmlspecialchars($alt)
    );
}
```

In this example, first the data is extracted inside the `foreach`. Then it is compiled into the output string with [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprtinf). This function is common and helpful to substitute variables into a pattern, e.g. to re-use the same value in the string by it's numeric parameter position (here: `3` in `%3$s`, `s` is for string, `d` is for digit).

Comment: I'm sure this code is good but it's more than I need to achieve my goal, thanks.